# How to run Javascript inside HTML webpage in scala-play with selenium (testing)

Tags: javascript, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scalatest

```
<button id="button1" onclick="function1();">press me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function function1() {
            alert("hello world");
        }
</script>
```

I want to test with Selenium that on click "button1" function1 of the script is executed.

I have this code in my test:

```
implicit val webDriver: HtmlUnitDriver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38)
  ...
it should "button test" in {
    go to "http://localhost:9000/test/selenium"
    pageTitle should be ("Test Selenium")
    webDriver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)

    click on webDriver.findElement(By.id("button1"))

    eventually {
        val alertTest: String = webDriver.switchTo().alert().getText
        alertTest should be ("hello world")
    }
}
```

I noticed that Selenium doesn't execute scripts inside my page like the code above. Is there another way to test JavaScript behavior with Scala-Play applications?